# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, sql, pdo

**Hello everyone,**
I've got a problem with my php code. I keep getting this error 0 1 2 3Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. As I understand it means that the number of parameters doesn't match. I rewrited it many times and I'm pretty sure, that everything in this line `$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, day, month, year, sex, vkey) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";` is ok. Any ideas how to fix it?

**Class code**

```
class Login
{
  public $host = "localhost";
  public $user  = "root";
  public $password = "****";
  public $database = "mydb";
  public $usersTable = "users";
  public $connect_timeout = 15;
  public $dbConnect = false;
  public $conn;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->database; connect_timeout=$this->connect_timeout", $this->user, $this->password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
  private function getData($sqlQuery, $var)
  {
    try
    {
      $result = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
      $result->execute([$var]);
      $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $row;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
  private function insData($sqlQuery, $var)
  {
    try
    {
      $query = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
      $query->execute([$var]);
      return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
  public function signup($mail, $pwd, $rpt, $sex, $fname, $lname, $day, $month, $year)
  {
    echo "0";
    if($pwd == $rpt)
    {
      echo "1";
      if($this->validateDate($day, $month, $year))
      {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?";
        $var = "$mail";
        echo "2";
        if(empty($this->getData($sqlQuery, $var)))
        {
          $pwd = $this->hashPwd($pwd);
          $vkey = $this->vKey();
          $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, day, month, year, sex, vkey) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
          $var = "$mail, $pwd, $fname, $lname, $day, $month, $year, $sex, $vkey";
          echo "3";
          if($this->insData($sqlQuery, $var) /*&& $this->sendMail($mail)*/)
          {
            echo "4";
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

**Form code**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST["mail"]) || !empty($_POST["pwd"]) || !empty($_POST["rpt"]) || !empty($_POST["sex"]) || !empty($_POST["fname"]) || !empty($_POST["lname"]) || !empty($_POST["day"]) ||
  !empty($_POST["month"]) || !empty($_POST["year"]))
{
  include "includes/main.inc.php";
  $login = new login();
  $login->signup($_POST["mail"], $_POST["pwd"], $_POST["rpt"], $_POST["sex"], $_POST["fname"], $_POST["lname"], $_POST["day"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["year"]);
  //header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
  <main>
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail"> <br> <br>
      <input type="password" name="pwd"  placeholder="Password"> <br> <br>
      <input type="password" name="rpt" placeholder="Repeat password"> <br> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="1">Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="2">Female <br> <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"> <br> <br>
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"> <br> <br>
      <select name="day">
        <option>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
      </select>
      <select name="month">
        <option>Month</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">Febuary</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
      </select>
      <select name="year">
        <option>Year</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
        <option value="1946">1946</option>
        <option value="1945">1945</option>
        <option value="1944">1944</option>
        <option value="1943">1943</option>
        <option value="1942">1942</option>
        <option value="1941">1941</option>
        <option value="1940">1940</option>
        <option value="1939">1939</option>
        <option value="1938">1938</option>
        <option value="1937">1937</option>
        <option value="1936">1936</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1933">1933</option>
        <option value="1932">1932</option>
        <option value="1931">1931</option>
        <option value="1930">1930</option>
        <option value="1929">1929</option>
        <option value="1928">1928</option>
        <option value="1927">1927</option>
        <option value="1926">1926</option>
        <option value="1925">1925</option>
        <option value="1924">1924</option>
        <option value="1923">1923</option>
        <option value="1922">1922</option>
        <option value="1921">1921</option>
        <option value="1920">1920</option>
        <option value="1919">1919</option>
        <option value="1918">1918</option>
        <option value="1917">1917</option>
        <option value="1916">1916</option>
        <option value="1915">1915</option>
        <option value="1914">1914</option>
        <option value="1913">1913</option>
        <option value="1912">1912</option>
        <option value="1911">1911</option>
        <option value="1910">1910</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
    </form>
  </main>
```

And my mysql table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpAZ.jpg

Comment: Check if you are REALLY passing all necessary variables to the function, just echo them one by one. The issue might be that your count is ok, but variable is not defined.

Comment: I think `$var` should be an array of values, it looks like a single string at the moment, so `$var = [ $mail, $pwd, $fname, ... ]`

Comment: @NigelRen spot on! But I thought that he uses some class, like I do where I pass variables comma separated, if not, then yes the PHP might view it as one variable.

Comment: Thank you all guys @NigelRen is right. I thought that I can do it in my function       `$query->execute([$var]);`

Comment: @Undry`if (!is_array($var)) { $var = array_map('trim', explode(',', $var)); }`

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo The problem with `explode` is that it may affect the data if it has a comma in an of the fields.

Comment: @NigelRen even if your `$var` is something like `$var = 'item'`, your `$var` will be transformed into array like `$var = [ 'item' ]`. http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?%0A$var%20=%20%27item%27;%0A$var%20=%20array_map(%27trim%27,%20explode(%27,%27,%20$var));%0Avar_dump($var);%0A?%3E

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo What if your data is `$i = "a,b,c"; $b="d";` and you do `$var = "$i, $b"`

Comment: @NigelRen that's a complex situation and should be treated separately. And that's not a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execute` only accepts array of parameters, but you send the parameters as string.

Change this code:

```
$query->execute([$var]);
```

to

```
$query->execute($var);
```

And this code:

```
$var = "$mail, $pwd, $fname, $lname, $day, $month, $year, $sex, $vkey";
```

to

```
$var = [
    $mail,
    $pwd,
    $fname,
    $lname,
    $day,
    $month,
    $year,
    $sex,
    $vkey
];
```